# Is `__value` a gcc extension, and if so, what does it do? Does it have a VC++ equivalent?

Tags: c, visual-c++, gcc, visual-studio-2012, cygwin

Title says it all.

I am trying to use some of the libraries from cygwin's gcc with visual studio's C++ compiler but the following code from `C:\cygwin\usr\include\sys\_types.h` does not compile:

```
#ifndef __mbstate_t_defined
/* Conversion state information.  */
typedef struct
{
  int __count;
  union
  {
    wint_t __wch;
    unsigned char __wchb[4];
  } __value;        /* Value so far.  */
} _mbstate_t;
#endif
```

Build Output:

```
1>c:\cygwin\usr\include\sys\_types.h(74): error C4980: '__value' : use of this keyword requires /clr:oldSyntax command line option
1>c:\cygwin\usr\include\sys\_types.h(74): error C2059: syntax error : '__value'
```

Visual Studio seems to be interpreting this as [some sort of CLR extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa712839%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: Doesn't the first line of the build output provide the solution? '`use of this keyword requires`` seems pretty clear.

Comment: @KenWhite No, that is a CLR keyword. I thought it was a GCC keyword.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is `__value` a gcc extension, and if so, what does it do? Does it have a VC++ equivalent?

It's the other way around. It's a [keyword in VC++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7kkeb76%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) but not in `gcc`.

In `gcc`, it's just an identifier.

Comment: I see... Is there a way to prevent VC++ from interpreting this as a keyword (other than replacing every instance of it)?

Comment: @Navin: There probably is. However, I haven't been able to find it yet.

Answer (score 3):

This [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-us/vcgeneral/thread/ADABF801-8006-47BD-9495-972E04DF5C78) says

> C/C++ Standards explicitly says that identifiers that contains double underscore are reserved: 
>   ISO.IEC 14882:2003 C++ Standard, section 17.4.3.1.2 "Global names":
>   "Certain sets of names and function signatures are always reserved to the implementation:
>   -- Each name that contains a double uderscore (__) or begins with an underscore followed by an upper-case letter (2.11) is reserved to the implementation for any use. ..."

Since it looks like Visual Studio uses the `__value` keyword in Managed Extensions for C++, could you maybe just rename `__value` to something else (like `__Value`)?

[the MSDN link above also has a dicsussion whether this is a bug in unmanaged C, the Microsoft reply seems to be that this is "by design"]